# how to make apache respond to traffic from given address range only?

Tags: apache

I know the `<Directory>` directive but it responds forbidden page so anyone in the internet is able to see that there is a server running.

But my question is there a global rule that if a packed comes from outside range there is nothing send.

Is such an option in Apache configs or must I use firewall for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive tells Apache which IP(s) and port(s) to bind to.

`Listen 127.0.0.1:80` should work.